# Angular 2 - My application stuck when I want to update firebase data in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

I’m trying to update multiple values in the firebase but I have small problem in the below code.
My application works fine in the first click on update button.
But when I click on update button again, I don’t know why the application stuck.

```
public list1: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
public list2: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
...
...

function(id,title,desc){
  this.list1.subscribe(dataX => {
    dataX.forEach(L1=> {
      if(L1.nID==id){
        this.list1.update(L1.$key, {
           title: title,
           desc: desc
         })
       }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out the docs for firebase here on Stackoverflow Document link at top of page... Search on Firebase...

Comment: try to add take operator `this.list1.take(1).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are subscribing on data which is self updating, resulting in a strange loop/lock.

`this.list1.subscribe(` will subscribe to every change in list1, so if there is an update in list1 this function is triggered.

In short: 
The `this.list1.update(` will update list1, which will trigger `this.list1.subscribe(` which will trigger `this.list1.update(` which will trigger `this.list1.subscribe(` and so on ...

To solve this you can use what mohamad rabee said in the comments and use `this.list1.take(1).subscribe(...)`

But if this isn't intended behavior and you want to subscribe to all updates to list1, then consider removing the update function from the subscribe.

Hope this helps you out in some way,

Regards